# Understanding the math tikzlibrary

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

In my question [The Spiral of Roots in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155087/10898), the answer by Mark Wibrow caught my attention but while trying to edit the code I found myself struggling with an ifelse statement. What I am trying to achieve is just to put a 1 instead of the square root of one in the base of the first right triangle. I tried saying

```
if \n = 1 then {1} else {$\sqrt{\n}$}
```

but it does not work. I don't clearly understand the math library (page 652 of the pgfmanual) and how it works. I am pretty sure that where I have the ifelse statement is wrong; probably more outside of the declaration. I even tried

```
\p = (\n == \N && \N > 1) ? "$\sqrt{\n}$" : "1";
```

but no good. Any insight as to how to achieve the desired result.

```
\newcommand\sqrtspiral[2][]{%
\tikz[line cap=round, x=2cm,y=2cm, line join=round,#1]{%
\tikzmath{%
  int \n;
  \b = 0; \d = 1; \N = #2;
  for \n in {1,...,\N}{
    \l = (\n == \N && \N > 1) ? "red" : "black";
    \e = (\n == 1) ? " -- cycle" : "";
    {
      \path [rotate=\b, draw=\l] (0,0) -- (\d,1) -- (\d,0)
        node [\l, midway, anchor=\b+180] {1}
        \e (\d/2, 0)  node [fill=white] {if \n = 1 then {1} else {$\sqrt{\n}$}}; % edit here
      \path [draw=\l, rotate=\b] (\d-.1,0) |- ++(.1,.1);
    };
    \d = sqrt(1+(\d)^2); \b = \b + asin(1/\d);
  };
  {
    \path [rotate=\b, \l] (\d/2, 0) node [fill=white] {$\sqrt x$};
  };
}}}
```

Here is the link to the answer: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155222/10898)

A MWE follows (of course merely one):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\sqrtspiral[2][]{%
\tikz[line cap=round, x=2cm,y=2cm, line join=round,#1]{%
\tikzmath{%
  int \n;
  \b = 0; \d = 1; \N = #2;
  for \n in {1,...,\N}{
    \l = (\n == \N && \N > 1) ? "red" : "black";
    \e = (\n == 1) ? " -- cycle" : "";
    {
      \path [rotate=\b, draw=\l] (0,0) -- (\d,1) -- (\d,0)
        node [\l, midway, anchor=\b+180] {1}
        \e (\d/2, 0)  node [fill=white] {%
            if \n = 1  then {1} else {$\sqrt{\n}$} %edit here
        };
      \path [draw=\l, rotate=\b] (\d-.1,0) |- ++(.1,.1);
    };
    \d = sqrt(1+(\d)^2); \b = \b + asin(1/\d);
  };
  {
    \path [rotate=\b, \l] (\d/2, 0) node [fill=white] {$\sqrt x$};
  };
}}}

\sqrtspiral{10}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm baffled as well. I can get it to work when choosing between `1` and `2` or even `1` and `\n` but it doesn't work when `\sqrt` is used.

Comment: Its new to me so I cant say much @PaulGessler but probably they way its written it only accepts letters and numbers but not stuff in math mode. I think.

Answer (score 13):

First thing to know : everything inside `{ };` (with semicolon) is treated outside `tikzmath`. So you can't put `if` logic inside `{ };` (56.7 Executing Code Outside the Parser of the TikZ 3.0.0 manual, p.634).

Second thing to know : `if \n = 1 then {1} else {2}` has no `print` command, and the statements `1` and `2` are not valid evaluations in `tikzmath`, and we compare with `==`.
 So to correct this you have to do `if \n == 1 then {print{1};} else {print{2};};`.
 And here `print` is optional if you use math mode `$ $`, but is mandatory if you want something like `print{1};` or `print{Some text here};`([check this Mark Wibrow's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222859/9335)).

So in your case the correct code to put in the node is :

```
\tikzmath{ 
  if \n == 1 then {
    {$1$};
  } else {
    {$\sqrt{\n}$};
  };
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\newcommand\sqrtspiral[2][]{%
\tikz[line cap=round, x=2cm,y=2cm, line join=round,#1]{%
\tikzmath{%
  int \n;
  \b = 0; \d = 1; \N = #2;
  for \n in {1,...,\N}{
    \l = (\n == \N && \N > 1) ? "red" : "black";
    \e = (\n == 1) ? " -- cycle" : "";
    { % --------------------------------------------------- outside math library
      \path [rotate=\b, draw=\l] (0,0) -- (\d,1) -- (\d,0)
        node [\l, midway, anchor=\b+180] {1}
        \e (\d/2, 0)  node [fill=white] { \tikzmath{ % -- back in math library
            if \n == 1 then {
              {$1$}; % ------------------------- $1$ is outside math library
            } else {
              {$\sqrt{\n}$}; % --------- $\sqrt{\n}$ is outside math library
            };
          }% -------------------------------------------- outside math library
        };
      \path [draw=\l, rotate=\b] (\d-.1,0) |- ++(.1,.1);
    }; % -------------------------------------------------- back in math library
    \d = sqrt(1+(\d)^2); \b = \b + asin(1/\d);
  };
  { % ----------------------------------------------------- outside math library
    \path [rotate=\b, \l] (\d/2, 0) node [fill=white] {$\sqrt x$};
  }; % ---------------------------------------------------- back in math library
}}}

\begin{document}

\sqrtspiral{10}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that you know a lot about `tikzmath`. I also noticed it with your Cayley graph posting, and with your `print` question. Would you like to write an article on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org) on explaining `tikzmath` with such nice images? I gladly return the favor with a 500 bounty, but more important is that readers there will like it for sure. You could contact me via `stefan@texblog.net` if you like.

Answer (score 9):

Since it's just typesetting the node contents not using it for computation you can use a normal tex if:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\sqrtspiral[2][]{%
\tikz[line cap=round, x=2cm,y=2cm, line join=round,#1]{%
\tikzmath{%
  int \n;
  \b = 0; \d = 1; \N = #2;
  for \n in {1,...,\N}{
    \l = (\n == \N && \N > 1) ? "red" : "black";
    \e = (\n == 1) ? " -- cycle" : "";
    {
      \path [rotate=\b, draw=\l] (0,0) -- (\d,1) -- (\d,0)
        node [\l, midway, anchor=\b+180] {1}
        \e (\d/2, 0)  node [fill=white] {$\ifnum\n=1 1\else\sqrt{\n}\fi $};
      \path [draw=\l, rotate=\b] (\d-.1,0) |- ++(.1,.1);
    };
    \d = sqrt(1+(\d)^2); \b = \b + asin(1/\d);
  };
  {
    \path [rotate=\b, \l] (\d/2, 0) node [fill=white] {$\sqrt x$};
  };
}}}

\sqrtspiral{10}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Description of `"x"` in the [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) page 935:

> These operators are used to quote x. However, as every expression is expanded with \edef before
>   it is parsed, macros (e.g., font commands like \tt or \Huge) may need to be “protected” from this
>   expansion (e.g., \noexpand\Huge).

You can define a new macro

```
\newcommand\mysqrt{$\sqrt{\n}$}
```

and then use

```
\p = (\n == 1) ? 1 : "\noexpand\mysqrt";
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\newcommand\mysqrt{$\sqrt{\n}$}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\sqrtspiral[2][]{%
\tikz[line cap=round, x=2cm,y=2cm, line join=round,#1]{%
\tikzmath{%
  int \n;
  \b = 0; \d = 1; \N = #2;
  for \n in {1,...,\N}{
    \l = (\n == \N && \N > 1) ? "red" : "black";
    \e = (\n == 1) ? " -- cycle" : "";
    \p = (\n == 1) ? 1 : "\noexpand\mysqrt";
    {
      \path [rotate=\b, draw=\l] (0,0) -- (\d,1) -- (\d,0)
        node [\l, midway, anchor=\b+180] {1}
        \e (\d/2, 0)  node [fill=white] {\p};
      \path [draw=\l, rotate=\b] (\d-.1,0) |- ++(.1,.1);
    };
    \d = sqrt(1+(\d)^2); \b = \b + asin(1/\d);
  };
  {
    \path [rotate=\b, \l] (\d/2, 0) node [fill=white] {$\sqrt x$};
  };
}}}

\sqrtspiral{10}

\end{document}
```